# Change the decorators of an html according to the device (mobile or a pc)

Tags: android, spring-mvc

I have a spring mvc web application and I need to give access some pages for mobile devices. But the problem is I need to apply different set of decorators for the mobile view.(that is when a user access that page using a mobile device get a different view rather than the view of that html view in pc). Here I am using site mesh. Is there any general approach that can overcome this scenario ? I have a plan to use user aget request tag to filter the device.

Answer (score 0):

yes , you may only use the User-Agent to deside

if you use PHP you may look at  [this](http://code.google.com/p/php-mobile-detect/)

or you may use the regex code for other language like this

```
protected $phoneDevices = array(     
        'iPhone' => '(iPhone.*Mobile|iPod|iTunes)',            
        'BlackBerry' => 'BlackBerry|rim[0-9]+',
        'HTC' => 'HTC|Desire',
        'Nexus' => 'Nexus One|Nexus S',
        'DellStreak' => 'Dell Streak',
        'Motorola' => '\bDroid\b.*Build|HRI39|MOT\-',
        'Samsung' => 'Samsung|GT-I9100|GT-I9000|GT-I9020|SCH-A310|SCH-A530|SCH-A570|SCH-A610|SCH-A630|SCH-A650|SCH-A790|SCH-A795|SCH-A850|SCH-A870|SCH-A890|SCH-A930|SCH-A950|SCH-A970|SCH-A990|SCH-I100|SCH-I110|SCH-I400|SCH-I405|SCH-I500|SCH-I510|SCH-I515|SCH-I600|SCH-I730|SCH-I760|SCH-I770|SCH-I830|SCH-I910|SCH-I920|SCH-LC11|SCH-N150|SCH-N300|SCH-R300|SCH-R400|SCH-R410|SCH-T300|SCH-U310|SCH-U320|SCH-U350|SCH-U360|SCH-U365|SCH-U370|SCH-U380|SCH-U410|SCH-U430|SCH-U450|SCH-U460|SCH-U470|SCH-U490|SCH-U540|SCH-U550|SCH-U620|SCH-U640|SCH-U650|SCH-U660|SCH-U700|SCH-U740|SCH-U750|SCH-U810|SCH-U820|SCH-U900|SCH-U940|SCH-U960|SCS-26UC|SGH-A107|SGH-A117|SGH-A127|SGH-A137|SGH-A157|SGH-A167|SGH-A177|SGH-A187|SGH-A197|SGH-A227|SGH-A237|SGH-A257|SGH-A437|SGH-A517|SGH-A597|SGH-A637|SGH-A657|SGH-A667|SGH-A687|SGH-A697|SGH-A697|SGH-A707|SGH-A717|SGH-A727|SGH-A737|SGH-A747|SGH-A767|SGH-A777|SGH-A797|SGH-A817|SGH-A827|SGH-A837|SGH-A847|SGH-A867|SGH-A877|SGH-A887|SGH-A897|SGH-A927|SGH-C207|SGH-C225|SGH-C417|SGH-D307|SGH-D347|SGH-D357|SGH-D407|SGH-D415|SGH-D807|SGH-E105|SGH-E315|SGH-E316|SGH-E317|SGH-E335|SGH-E635|SGH-E715|SGH-I577|SGH-I607|SGH-I617|SGH-I627|SGH-I637|SGH-I677|SGH-I717|SGH-I727|SGH-I777|SGH-I827|SGH-I847|SGH-I857|SGH-I897|SGH-I907|SGH-I917|SGH-I927|SGH-I937|SGH-I997|SGH-N105|SGH-N625|SGH-P107|SGH-P207|SGH-P735|SGH-P777|SGH-Q105|SGH-R225|SGH-S105|SGH-S307|SGH-T109|SGH-T119|SGH-T139|SGH-T209|SGH-T219|SGH-T229|SGH-T239|SGH-T249|SGH-T259|SGH-T309|SGH-T319|SGH-T329|SGH-T339|SGH-T349|SGH-T359|SGH-T369|SGH-T379|SGH-T409|SGH-T429|SGH-T439|SGH-T459|SGH-T469|SGH-T479|SGH-T499|SGH-T509|SGH-T519|SGH-T539|SGH-T559|SGH-T589|SGH-T609|SGH-T619|SGH-T629|SGH-T639|SGH-T659|SGH-T669|SGH-T679|SGH-T709|SGH-T719|SGH-T729|SGH-T739|SGH-T749|SGH-T759|SGH-T769|SGH-T809|SGH-T819|SGH-T839|SGH-T919|SGH-T919|SGH-T929|SGH-T939|SGH-T939|SGH-T959|SGH-T989|SGH-V205|SGH-V206|SGH-X105|SGH-X426|SGH-X427|SGH-X475|SGH-X495|SGH-X497|SGH-X507|SGH-ZX10|SGH-ZX20|SPH-A120|SPH-A400|SPH-A420|SPH-A460|SPH-A500I|SPH-A560|SPH-A600|SPH-A620|SPH-A660|SPH-A700|SPH-A740|SPH-A760|SPH-A790|SPH-A800|SPH-A820|SPH-A840|SPH-A880|SPH-A900|SPH-A940|SPH-A960|SPH-D600|SPH-D700|SPH-D710|SPH-D720|SPH-I300|SPH-I325|SPH-I330|SPH-I350|SPH-I500|SPH-I600|SPH-I700|SPH-L700|SPH-M100|SPH-M220|SPH-M240|SPH-M300|SPH-M305|SPH-M320|SPH-M330|SPH-M350|SPH-M360|SPH-M370|SPH-M380|SPH-M510|SPH-M540|SPH-M550|SPH-M560|SPH-M570|SPH-M580|SPH-M610|SPH-M620|SPH-M630|SPH-M800|SPH-M810|SPH-M850|SPH-M900|SPH-M910|SPH-M920|SPH-M930|SPH-N200|SPH-N240|SPH-N300|SPH-N400|SPH-Z400|SWC-E100',
        'Sony' => 'E10i|SonyEricsson|SonyEricssonLT15iv',
        'Asus' => 'Asus.*Galaxy',
        'Palm' => 'PalmSource|Palm', // avantgo|blazer|elaine|hiptop|plucker|xiino
        'GenericPhone' => '(mmp|pocket|psp|symbian|Smartphone|smartfon|treo|up.browser|up.link|vodafone|wap|nokia|Series40|Series60|S60|SonyEricsson|N900|\bPPC\b|MAUI.*WAP.*Browser|LG\-P500)'
);
// List of tablet devices.
protected $tabletDevices = array(
    'BlackBerryTablet' => 'PlayBook|RIM Tablet',
    'iPad' => 'iPad.*Mobile',
    'Kindle' => 'Kindle|Silk.*Accelerated',
    'SamsungTablet' => 'SAMSUNG.*Tablet|Galaxy.*Tab|GT-P1000|GT-P1010|GT-P6210|GT-P6800|GT-P6810|GT-P7100|GT-P7300|GT-P7310|GT-P7500|GT-P7510|SCH-I800|SCH-I815|SCH-I905|SGH-I777|SGH-I957|SGH-I987|SGH-T849|SGH-T859|SGH-T869|SGH-T989|SPH-D710|SPH-P100',
    'MotorolaTablet' => 'xoom|sholest',
    'AsusTablet' => 'Transformer|TF101',
    'NookTablet' => 'NookColor|nook browser|BNTV250A|LogicPD Zoom2',
    'AcerTablet' => 'Android.*(A100|A101|A200|A500|A501|A510|W500|W500P|W501|W501P)',
    'GenericTablet' => 'Tablet|ViewPad7|LG\-V909|MID7015|BNTV250A|LogicPD Zoom2|\bA7EB\b|CatNova8|A1_07|CT704|CT1002|\bM721\b',
);
// List of mobile Operating Systems.
protected $operatingSystems = array(
    'AndroidOS' => '(android.*mobile|android(?!.*mobile))',
    'BlackBerryOS' => '(blackberry|rim tablet os)',
    'PalmOS' => '(avantgo|blazer|elaine|hiptop|palm|plucker|xiino)',
    'SymbianOS' => 'Symbian|SymbOS|Series60|Series40|\bS60\b',
    'WindowsMobileOS' => 'IEMobile|Windows Phone|Windows CE.*(PPC|Smartphone)|MSIEMobile|Window Mobile|XBLWP7',
    'iOS' => '(iphone|ipod|ipad)',
    'FlashLiteOS' => '',
    'JavaOS' => '',
    'NokiaOS' => '',
    'webOS' => '',
    'badaOS' => '\bBada\b',
    'BREWOS' => '',
);
// List of mobile User Agents.
protected $userAgents = array(      
  'Chrome' => '\bCrMo\b',
  'Dolfin' => '\bDolfin\b',
  'Opera' => '(Opera.*Mini|Opera.*Mobi)',  
  'Skyfire' => 'skyfire',      
  'IE' => 'ie*mobile',
  'Firefox' => 'fennec|firefox.*maemo',
  'Bolt' => 'bolt',
  'TeaShark' => 'teashark',
  'Blazer' => 'Blazer',
  'Safari' => 'Mobile*Safari',
  'Midori' => 'midori',
  'GenericBrowser' => 'NokiaBrowser|OviBrowser'
);
```

it's easy to reuse  :)